# Styling Hyperlink inside a TextBlock

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, styles

One of the columns in my `DataGrid` contains a `Hyperlink` in a `TextBlock`. When a row is selected, the hyperlink shows as blue on blue, so i want to change it's text color to white. How can I do that?

The `DataGrid` looks like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Title">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Url}">
                            <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I've tried

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and the same code with `TextElement` instead of `TextBlock`. Both work for other columns, but not for this one with hyperlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following declaration for the link:

```
<Run Text="{Binding Title}" 
     Foreground="{Binding 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridCell},
                                        Path=Foreground}"/>
```

Comment: This makes the hyperlink the correct color when selected, but also makes it black when not selected and I don't want that.

Comment: Extend your style to fit your requirements

Comment: Heh, that didn't occur to me. Yeah it works now, thanks. I'm still curious whether there is a better way to do it, though.

Comment: Can you post the XAML to show *how* you extended the style, please?

Comment: @Mal Ross: Sorry, I'm currently no more deep enough in the topic to give you a quick example. I propose that you post a new question.

Comment: @HCL: No problem; I was directing the question at svick, really, but have posted [my own problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182135/how-to-propagate-styles-to-hyperlinks-inside-a-datatemplate) anyway.