# How to propagate styles to Hyperlinks inside a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, hyperlink, styles, datatemplate

I'm try to set the `Foreground` colour on a `Hyperlink` using a `Style` object in an ancestor's `Resources`, but it's not having any effect. I even used the `BasedOn` tip from [Changing Hyperlink foreground without losing hover color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252889/), but it's not made any difference - I still get a blue hyperlink that is red on hover.

Here's the XAML for my controls, including an `ItemsControl` whose items are shown using a hyperlink:

```
<StackPanel Background="Red" TextElement.Foreground="White">
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <TextBlock>Data import errors</TextBlock>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And the items in the `ItemsControl` are picking up the following `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Importer:ConversionDetailsMessage}">
  <TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    <Hyperlink Command="Common:ImportDataCommands.ExplainConversionMessage" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
      <Run Text="{Binding HelpLink.Item2, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

It's worth noting, too, that I don't want to just set the different colours directly on the `Hyperlink` in the `DataTemplate`. This is because the template will be used by *a number* of different `ItemsControl` objects, most of which will be on a white background and so can use the standard hyperlink colours. (Note that the one in the XAML above, however, has a red background.)

In short, I don't want the `DataTemplate` to have to know anything about the control in which it's being used. The styles for the template's controls should just filter down to it.

So... can anyone tell me why the style's not filtering down and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks.

**Update:**
Since I couldn't get Pavlo's answer to work in my production app, I've since tried it in a separate test app. The app is a WinForms app, with the main form containing nothing but an `ElementHost`, which itself contains a simple WPF usercontrol. Here's its XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataTemplateStyling.StylingView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:DataTemplateStyling="clr-namespace:DataTemplateStyling"
             x:Name="root" Loaded="StylingViewLoaded">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTemplateStyling:ImportMessage}">
      <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle}"/>
      </DataTemplate.Resources>
      <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding HelpLink.Item1}">
          <Run Text="{Binding HelpLink.Item2, Mode=OneTime}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
      </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
    <StackPanel Background="Red" TextElement.Foreground="White">
      <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle" TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </StackPanel.Resources>
      <TextBlock>Data import errors</TextBlock>
      <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As it stands above, this generates an `InvalidOperationException`, stating "Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'IFrameworkInputElement'."

That can be fixed by putting `TargetType="Hyperlink"` on the `Style` definition immediately inside the `UserControl.Resources` element. However, while the messages are being shown, the link part of them still has the default blue hyperlink styling:

[image: Blue hyperlinks persist]

In short, it's not working, so I'd welcome any other suggestions/corrections. :(

**Update 2:**
Thanks to an alternative solution from Pavlo, it now **is** working. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some googling I ran into this post: http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html.

As it described there, it turns out that elements that are not derived from `Control` (like `TextBlock` and `Hyperlink`) do not look for implicit styles outside the `DataTemplate` boundary.

Again, as the article says, the possible workaround is to specify the style key explicitly. In your case it might be something like this:

```
<StackPanel Background="Red" TextElement.Foreground="White">
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle" TargetType="Hyperlink" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <TextBlock>Data import errors</TextBlock>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Errors}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Then, you can add an implicit style for `Hyperlink` that just references our named style in the `DataTemplate` resources:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Importer:ConversionDetailsMessage}">
  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle}"/>
  </DataTemplate.Resources>
  <TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    <Hyperlink Command="Common:ImportDataCommands.ExplainConversionMessage" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
      <Run Text="{Binding HelpLink.Item2, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
  </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

And because the data template can be used in different places, there is a possibility that parent container doesn't define a style with key "MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle". In this case an exception will be thrown saying that resource "MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle" cannot be found. To address this, you can define a style with such key that will only inherit default style somewhere in App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}/>
```

**Update:**

The code you included in your update will not work because of the nature of static resources, which means that the following resource reference in date template...

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle}"
```

... will always point to the following resource (which is the default style):

```
<Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}"/>
```

Static resource references are resolved at compile time, therefore the closest resource in the tree is used.

You might be tempted to use `DynamicResource`, but unfortunately it is not supported with the `BasedOn` property.

BUT, `Foreground` property supports dynamic resources, so we can use the same trick with brushes we use inside our style. Here is your test user control modified to use dynamic brushes:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DataTemplateStyling.StylingView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:DataTemplateStyling="clr-namespace:DataTemplateStyling"
             x:Name="root"
             Loaded="StylingViewLoaded">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkForeground"
                         Color="Blue" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkHoverForeground"
                         Color="Gray" />

        <Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle"
               TargetType="Hyperlink"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource HyperlinkForeground}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource HyperlinkHoverForeground}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DataTemplateStyling:ImportMessage}">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle}" />
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}" />
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding HelpLink.Item1}">
                    <Run Text="{Binding HelpLink.Item2, Mode=OneTime}" />
                </Hyperlink>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">
        <StackPanel Background="Red"
                    TextElement.Foreground="White">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkForeground"
                                 Color="Yellow" />

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkHoverForeground"
                                 Color="White" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock>Data import errors</TextBlock>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It works as expected, i.e. all links inside `StackPanel` will be Yellow/White, while outside they will be blue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome googling skills - thanks! And a very complete answer. I'll just try this out and mark it as accepted once I've got it working.

Comment: Forgot my app is a WinForms app using an `ElementHost`, so I don't have an app.xaml file. Still, the principle seemed sound, so I tried adding an empty `MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle` immediately before the `DataTemplate` in my `UserControl`'s resource dictionary and left the specific `StackPanel` seen above to replace it with its own definition. Sadly, it's still not working. I'll keep on trying things...

Comment: @Mal - Didn't you forget including style in the data template itself: `<DataTemplate.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle}"/>
  </DataTemplate.Resources>`?

Comment: @Pavlo: No, I put that in there. :-/

Comment: @Mal - Just tried inside ElementHost in a WinForms project. It works perfectly. Check your code.

Comment: Hi Pavlo, I've copied and pasted your code above into a very simple test app and it's still not working. And yes, I have checked my code. ;) Were there any differences between your own test app and the code above? BTW, see the update in my original question to see exactly what XAML I'm using. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mal - Yeah, now I see. The problem is that static resources are resolved at runtime, hence the `BasedOn="{StaticResource MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle}"` reference in the `DataTemplate` is resolved to nearest resource in the tree (which is `<Style x:Key="MyDefaultHyperlinkStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Hyperlink}}"/>`), while the `ItemsControl` is a dynamic thing, i.e. by the time when items are created (at runtime) all the resources already resolved and the resource defined in `StackPanel.Resources` is not taken into account.

Comment: @Mal - That being said, you might be tempted to replace `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`, but, unfortunately, it is not allowed on `BasedOn` property of the `Style`... So, the only thing left is to define the correct style BEFORE the `DataTemplate` in the tree (i.e. if you put the correct style from `StackPanel.Resources` to `UserControl.Resources` it will work).

Comment: Ah, that's a pity. I need different `ItemsControl`s to have different hyperlink styles, yet still use the same `DataTemplate`. Sounds like I'm trying to do something that's impossible, given the current restrictions in the framework code. I suppose I could always change my ViewModel class (`ImportMessage` in my code above) to include information about the desired colours and then just bind to the relevant properties. Not ideal, but I guess it's simple enough. Thanks for all of your help - it was enlightening.

Comment: @Pavlo - BTW, if you want to amend your answer to say that I can't do exactly what I want in XAML alone (but leave the rest of the answer there too), I'll mark it as the accepted answer.